# Android library project Sliding Menu throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.R$styleable

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, noclassdeffounderror, slidingmenu

I'm developing an android application and I'm trying to use a library Sliding Menu (github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). However, I have a problem in using the library in a clean project. I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.R$styleable
```

when doing

```
SlidingMenu slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu();
```

Configurations tested:
JDK tested 1.6u43, 1.7(latest)
Project target api = tried both Android 4.2.2 and Google API 17
SDK versions tested 21, 21.0.1, 21.1
Windows 8 Pro x64, Intel Core i7 3610QM, Nvidia GT660M, Samsung Pro 840 256GB SSD
Integrated both with Actionbarsherlock and without it.

I import the library, by creating an Android Project from Existing Code, marking "Is Library" in the android properties, and then referrencing it in the original application android properties (not via .jar)

Below links to code snippets, full stacktrace and screenshots of current configurations

Code snippet:
http://pastebin.com/2yzRC5AJ

Full Stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/D7RQwuQd

I've been stuck on this for 3 days now... :/

Comment: If you go to properties, do you see it in your buildpath?

Comment: http://scr.hu/0hoo/we9bw
Adding it to required projects on build path and then moving it up in order/export just throws erorr that SlidingMenu.apk was not found, behaviour stays the same

Comment: Hey, anybody has a solution for this? I encountered something very similar when trying to use my own library project.

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the dependency two ways before I eradicated my noclassdef errors

1. Add the library.jar from /bin as dependency to your build path, make sure to select the Order and Export tab and select the check box as well for the new dependency.
2. Add the library via right mouse click on your project, then properties, then android then add library
3. Voilla

I struggled with this as well, and from a vast number of google searches, managed to piece this together.

Hope it helps..

Comment: was exactly my problem, with the same library, thank you. there might be a mismatch in the Android Support v4 library and it can be solved by copying your project's support library and replace the support library of the Sliding menu project by your copied jar and Hopla! working.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution :
If your project already contain support library then just delete support library from library(jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu) and then every thing works fine.you can do it after import also.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just add the library to the properties of your project (ANDROID);
2) And mark the same in Order & Export property of (JAVA BUILD PATH);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Since you're building the app with IDE, you need to tell the **IDE** that this module is a **Library**, thus defining the library in .properties file would be useless. Try change the IDE build file, I'm not familiar with eclipse, but in android studio this lines would be enough:

**module.iml**

```
<configuration>
    <option name="LIBRARY_PROJECT" value="true" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manifast and change sdkversion to 11